# Excel Function that will match based on the current row looking backwards

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am trying to create/find a function in Excel that will work similarly to XMATCH. I cannot figure out however, how to make it look backwards from the current value. I have attached the image of the desired outcome below. I want the formula to return as per Column C.

[image: Desired Outcome]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this formula:

```
=INDEX($B$1:$B$6,XMATCH(A1-1,FILTER($A$1:$A$6,ROW($A$1:$A$6)<ROW()),0,-1))
```

It filters the range for XMATCH according to the current row and searches backwards (= parameter -1)

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much. That works great. I'll have a look into the way you used FILTER and ROW to achieve this so I further understand it.